# cut command in CMD

Tags: kubectl, minikube, cut

I'm trying to access the script below, however, I'm getting the error that:

> 'cut' is not recognized as an internal or external command

```
kubectl get pods -n argocd -l app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-server -o name | cut -d'/' -f 2
```

What can I do to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Windows.

`cut` is a Linux command that "cuts" the output, in this case, what's being piped from the `kubectl` command, by the delimiter given (i.e. `/`) and returning the second (`2`) field.

Because `kubectl ... --output=name` returns the long name of a resource, in this case something of the form `pod/[name]`, the command will return the pod's name.

You should be able to replace this with:

```sh
kubectl get pods \
--namespace=argocd \
--selector=app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-server \
--output=jsonpath="{.metadata.name}"
```

The `\` are included to pretty-print. You may drop all of them and put everything on a single line if that doesn't work on Windows.